# unattended-upgrades not starting to update at shutdown

Tags: apt, server, updates, shutdown, unattended-upgrades

I have a new build here with Ubuntu Server 20.04, mainly as a NAS but also as a Jellyfin media server.

I want it to perform its updates by itself, thanks to unattended-upgrades, as the end user would not know how to do it by himself.

As this server is not going to be on 24/7, I would like it starting the update process at the computer shutdown, thanks to the related option of unattended-upgrades.

This is what i did so far:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/21auto-upgrades
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "1";
APT::Periodic::AutocleanInterval "7";
APT::Periodic::RandomSleep "1";
APT::Periodic::Verbose "2";
```

And

```
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
    "${distro_id}ESMApps:${distro_codename}-apps-security";
    "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}-infra-security";
    "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    "grub*";
    "jellyfin*";
};

Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Kernel-Packages "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::Verbose "true";
Unattended-Upgrade::Debug "true";

Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";
```

(As Grub requires human inputs and Jellyfin is not 'stable' yet, I choose to not update them)

I have read that it is good to increase the default 30 seconds of InhibitDelayMaxSec, in case the update process takes more time.
So I put 30 minutes to be safe in the two following config files:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/logind.conf.d/unattended-upgrades-logind-maxdelay.conf
-> InhibitDelayMaxSec=1800

$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
-> InhibitDelayMaxSec=1800
```

Here is the log of unattended-upgrades (`/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`):

```
2020-08-31 10:08:54,859 DEBUG Running on the development release
2020-08-31 10:08:54,860 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2020-08-31 10:08:54,862 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=focal, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=focal-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=focal-infra-security, o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates
2020-08-31 10:08:54,863 INFO Initial blacklist: grub* jellyfin*
2020-08-31 10:08:54,863 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict):
2020-08-31 10:08:55,351 DEBUG Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.jellyfin.org_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=,c=main,v=,o=Jellyfin,l=Jellyfin arch='amd64' site='repo.jellyfin.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=3920 ID:26> with -32768 pin
2020-08-31 10:08:55,351 DEBUG Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/ch.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en'  a=focal-backports,c=universe,v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,l=Ubuntu arch='' site='ch.archive.ubuntu.com' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=3232 ID:17> with -32768 pin
2020-08-31 10:08:55,352 DEBUG Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/ch.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=focal-backports,c=universe,v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,l=Ubuntu arch='amd64' site='ch.archive.ubuntu.com' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=12498 ID:16> with -32768 pin
2020-08-31 10:08:55,700 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=26, priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.jellyfin.org_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=,c=main,v=,o=Jellyfin,l=Jellyfin arch='amd64' site='repo.jellyfin.org' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=3920 ID:26>
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=17, priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/ch.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_universe_i18n_Translation-en'  a=focal-backports,c=universe,v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,l=Ubuntu arch='' site='ch.archive.ubuntu.com' IndexType='Debian Translation Index' Size=3232 ID:17>
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgFilePin(id=16, priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pin -32768 to package_file: <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/ch.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_focal-backports_universe_binary-amd64_Packages'  a=focal-backports,c=universe,v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,l=Ubuntu arch='amd64' site='ch.archive.ubuntu.com' IndexType='Debian Package Index' Size=12498 ID:16>
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-uboot', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-legacy', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-doc', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,701 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-ipxe', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-emu', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-coreboot', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-arm64-signed', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-linuxbios', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-common', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-customizer', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-amd64-signed-template', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-invaders', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,702 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-coreboot-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-ieee1275-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-coreboot-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-xen-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-ieee1275-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-xen-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub2-common', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-legacy-doc', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-legacy-ec2', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,703 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-splashimages', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-yeeloong', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-pc', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-cloud-amd64', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-theme-breeze', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-imageboot', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-arm64', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-xen', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-pc-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-ia32-signed', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,704 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-pc-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-amd64-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-gfxpayload-lists', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-amd64-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grubzfs-testsuite', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-arm', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-rescue-pc', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub2-themes-ubuntustudio', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-ieee1275', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,705 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grun', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub2', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grunt', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-amd64', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-ia32', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-ia64', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-amd64-signed', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-ia32-bin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub2-splashimages', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,706 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-efi-ia32-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-emu-dbg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='grub-firmware-qemu', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfish', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfin-web', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfin-ffmpeg', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,707 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfish1', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,708 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfin-server', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,708 DEBUG Applying pinning: PkgPin(pkg='jellyfin', priority=-32768)
2020-08-31 10:08:55,719 DEBUG Using (^linux-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^kfreebsd-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^gnumach-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-modules-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-kernel-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^linux-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^kfreebsd-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^gnumach-.*-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-modules-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$|^.*-kernel-[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+-[0-9]+(-.+)?$) regexp to find kernel packages
2020-08-31 10:08:55,720 DEBUG Using (^linux-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^linux-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^gnumach-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^gnumach-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^.*-modules-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^.*-modules-5\.4\.0\-42$|^.*-kernel-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^.*-kernel-5\.4\.0\-42$|^linux-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^linux-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^kfreebsd-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^gnumach-.*-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^gnumach-.*-5\.4\.0\-42$|^.*-modules-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^.*-modules-5\.4\.0\-42$|^.*-kernel-5\.4\.0\-42\-generic$|^.*-kernel-5\.4\.0\-42$) regexp to find running kernel packages
2020-08-31 10:08:56,261 DEBUG Checking: apport ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:56,472 DEBUG Checking: bind9-dnsutils ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:56,691 DEBUG Checking: bind9-host ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:56,918 DEBUG Checking: bind9-libs ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,119 DEBUG Checking: curl ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,425 DEBUG Checking: jellyfin ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'' origin:'Jellyfin' label:'Jellyfin' site:'repo.jellyfin.org' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,432 DEBUG adjusting candidate version: jellyfin=10.6.2-1
2020-08-31 10:08:57,471 DEBUG Checking: jellyfin-server ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'' origin:'Jellyfin' label:'Jellyfin' site:'repo.jellyfin.org' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,478 DEBUG adjusting candidate version: jellyfin-server=10.6.2-1
2020-08-31 10:08:57,517 DEBUG Checking: jellyfin-web ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'' origin:'Jellyfin' label:'Jellyfin' site:'repo.jellyfin.org' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,524 DEBUG adjusting candidate version: jellyfin-web=10.6.2-1
2020-08-31 10:08:57,598 DEBUG Checking: libcurl3-gnutls ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:57,844 DEBUG Checking: libcurl4 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:58,056 DEBUG Checking: libdns-export1109 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:58,346 DEBUG Checking: libisc-export1105 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:58,605 DEBUG Checking: liblzma5 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:58,992 DEBUG Checking: python3-apport ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:59,215 DEBUG Checking: python3-problem-report ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:59,483 DEBUG Checking: rsyslog ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:08:59,758 DEBUG Checking: tmux ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:09:00,027 DEBUG Checking: xz-utils ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'focal-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'ch.archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
2020-08-31 10:09:00,643 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: apport
bind9-dnsutils
bind9-host
bind9-libs
curl
libcurl3-gnutls
libcurl4
libdns-export1109
libisc-export1105
liblzma5
python3-apport
python3-problem-report
rsyslog
tmux
xz-utils
2020-08-31 10:09:03,246 DEBUG fetch.run() result: 0
2020-08-31 10:09:03,611 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 427240 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/rsyslog_8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rsyslog/rsyslog_8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,612 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/rsyslog_8.2001.0-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,615 DEBUG found pkg: rsyslog
2020-08-31 10:09:03,616 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.rsyslogd 88fe4a6a37a5cbb88fcadf1e564874c2
2020-08-31 10:09:03,617 DEBUG current md5: 88fe4a6a37a5cbb88fcadf1e564874c2
2020-08-31 10:09:03,617 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/init.d/rsyslog bd41a0654a192d74dfb9c551b06fa855
2020-08-31 10:09:03,617 DEBUG current md5: bd41a0654a192d74dfb9c551b06fa855
2020-08-31 10:09:03,617 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/rsyslog 80e9fc074b97751dd4de99855bb8d0e0
2020-08-31 10:09:03,618 DEBUG current md5: 80e9fc074b97751dd4de99855bb8d0e0
2020-08-31 10:09:03,618 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog 8159203bf98416c898849057f585e31f
2020-08-31 10:09:03,618 DEBUG current md5: 8159203bf98416c898849057f585e31f
2020-08-31 10:09:03,618 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/rsyslog.conf 8f03326e3d7284ef50ac6777ef8a4fb8
2020-08-31 10:09:03,619 DEBUG current md5: 8f03326e3d7284ef50ac6777ef8a4fb8
2020-08-31 10:09:03,619 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 91724 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,619 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,620 DEBUG found pkg: liblzma5
2020-08-31 10:09:03,622 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/liblzma5_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,623 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 174936 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/libisc-export1105_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9-libs/libisc-export1105_9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,623 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/libisc-export1105_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,624 DEBUG found pkg: libisc-export1105
2020-08-31 10:09:03,626 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libisc-export1105_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,626 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 765124 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/libdns-export1109_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9-libs/libdns-export1109_9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,626 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/libdns-export1109_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,628 DEBUG found pkg: libdns-export1109
2020-08-31 10:09:03,630 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libdns-export1109_1%3a9.11.16+dfsg-3~ubuntu1_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,630 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 82508 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/xz-utils_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xz-utils/xz-utils_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,630 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/xz-utils_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,633 DEBUG found pkg: xz-utils
2020-08-31 10:09:03,633 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/xz-utils_5.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,633 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 134108 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-dnsutils_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-dnsutils_9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,634 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-dnsutils_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,634 DEBUG found pkg: bind9-dnsutils
2020-08-31 10:09:03,637 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-dnsutils_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,637 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 1115016 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-libs_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-libs_9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,637 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-libs_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,638 DEBUG found pkg: bind9-libs
2020-08-31 10:09:03,641 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-libs_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,641 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 43008 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-host_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/bind9/bind9-host_9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,641 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-host_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,641 DEBUG found pkg: bind9-host
2020-08-31 10:09:03,644 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/bind9-host_1%3a9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,644 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 9744 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,644 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,667 DEBUG found pkg: python3-problem-report
2020-08-31 10:09:03,669 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-problem-report_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,669 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 84336 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,669 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,674 DEBUG found pkg: python3-apport
2020-08-31 10:09:03,675 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,675 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 128400 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,676 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8_all.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,676 DEBUG found pkg: apport
2020-08-31 10:09:03,677 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/apport/blacklist.d/README.blacklist c2ed1eb9a17ec2550747b4960cf4b73c
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG current md5: c2ed1eb9a17ec2550747b4960cf4b73c
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/apport/blacklist.d/apport 44503501302b80099552bac0204a45c1
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG current md5: 44503501302b80099552bac0204a45c1
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/apport/crashdb.conf 4202dae3eccfa5bbb33a0a9acfcd3724
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG current md5: 4202dae3eccfa5bbb33a0a9acfcd3724
2020-08-31 10:09:03,678 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/bash_completion.d/apport_completion dfe766d9328bb5c895038b44185133f9
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG current md5: dfe766d9328bb5c895038b44185133f9
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/cron.daily/apport df5d3bc9ab3a67b58156376318077304
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG current md5: df5d3bc9ab3a67b58156376318077304
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/default/apport 3446c6cac185f44237f59786e006ebe4
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG current md5: 3446c6cac185f44237f59786e006ebe4
2020-08-31 10:09:03,679 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/init.d/apport f57e2de719f383ed276964881af116f8
2020-08-31 10:09:03,680 DEBUG current md5: f57e2de719f383ed276964881af116f8
2020-08-31 10:09:03,680 DEBUG conffile line: /etc/logrotate.d/apport fa54dab59ef899b48d5455c976008df4
2020-08-31 10:09:03,680 DEBUG current md5: fa54dab59ef899b48d5455c976008df4
2020-08-31 10:09:03,680 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 161428 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,680 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,681 DEBUG found pkg: curl
2020-08-31 10:09:03,683 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/curl_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,684 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 233028 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,684 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,685 DEBUG found pkg: libcurl4
2020-08-31 10:09:03,687 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl4_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,687 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 230936 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/curl/libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,688 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,689 DEBUG found pkg: libcurl3-gnutls
2020-08-31 10:09:03,691 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libcurl3-gnutls_7.68.0-1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,691 DEBUG <apt_pkg.AcquireItem object:Status: 2 Complete: 1 Local: 1 IsTrusted: 1 FileSize: 291668 DestFile:'/var/cache/apt/archives/tmux_3.0a-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb' DescURI: 'http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tmux/tmux_3.0a-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb' ID:0 ErrorText: ''>
2020-08-31 10:09:03,691 DEBUG check_conffile_prompt(/var/cache/apt/archives/tmux_3.0a-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb)
2020-08-31 10:09:03,694 DEBUG found pkg: tmux
2020-08-31 10:09:03,695 DEBUG No conffiles in deb /var/cache/apt/archives/tmux_3.0a-2ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb (There is no member named 'conffiles')
2020-08-31 10:09:03,695 DEBUG Packages blacklist due to conffile prompts: []
2020-08-31 10:09:03,695 DEBUG Configured to install on shutdown, so exiting now
```

According to the last line above, unattended-upgrades has been set up correctly to apply the updates on shutdown.

But after a `sudo shutdown -h now`, the server powered down instantly.
And at the next start, this is what I see:

```
18 updates can be installed immediately.
6 of these updates are security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
```

So obviously, nothing has been updated at shutdown...

Any clue why this is not working as expected?

Comment: Since you did not enable the Jellyfin repo, you don't need to blacklist the package. Jellyfin is not in the Ubuntu repositories, which are the only repositories in your Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins

Comment: The login message (`18 updates can be installed immediately`) is not generated at boot, nor at shutdown. So it might be out-of-date. Run `sudo apt update` before shutdown, and check the output for what upgrades should be really be installed. Check /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log for UU's start, stop, and logic. Um, some users think that a delayed shutdown indicates a problem, and will "helpfully" force a poweroff. I run Jellyfin, and have never had a problem with UU operating in the background.

Comment: You are right about Jellyfin not needed to be blacklisted. 
It is unclear to me, isn't UU supposed to perform `sudo apt update` by itself? 
Because if I recall correctly, I was in the same situation while trying to make UU working before activating the shutdown option: I had to manually `sudo apt update` before having UU doing the updates as waited.
Should I put `sudo apt update` in a cron? I really want this to be automatic for the end user.
Ok so I am going to put back the shutdown option to false as well as the InhibitDelayMaxSec to 30 sec and will report back what I get.

Comment: UU uses *two* randomizations. It runs apt-update at a random time once each day, and then apt-upgrade at a different random time. The randomness is to even out the load on the servers. You can see these with `systemctl list-timers` (In fact, you can see the login message creation script, motd-news on a similar semi-random schedule there, too).

Comment: One more thing...When you select "install on shutdown", UU *downloads* in the background while the system is running (it needs the network stack), and then waits to *install* those packages until shutdown. It's possible that UU did not work on shutdown as expected simply because it had not downloaded anything yet -- the apt-daily-upgrade.timer had not run yet. If you give it a couple days, it's likely to start working as all the required pieces hit their timers and fall into place.

Comment: Help much appreciated @user535733! I am now starting to wonder if UU and its randomness is the right option for this server. The latter is indeed going to be on a day or another only, and for a couple of hours at best from what I know. Maybe a weekly anacron right after startup that runs `apt update` `apt dist-upgrade` and `apt autoremove` should be better?

Comment: Good news: Anacron-like behavior is already baked in to systemd timers. Systemd will notice the missed job at the next startup, and run it few minutes later. Consider enabling the 'minimal steps' option in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades so a surprise shutdown command gets handled gracefully from the user point of view.

Comment: With the Shutdown option to false now everything seems to work fine. Should I post my latest config and some logs even if it's not an answer to the original question? ( I am new to this Ask - Comment - Answer way to do).

Comment: @user535733: wouldn't you mind sharing how you do enable the jellyfin repo? `apt-cache policy` is showing `release o=Jellyfin,n=focal,l=Jellyfin,c=main,b=amd64 origin repo.jellyfin.org` but `"Jellyfin:focal"` in 50unattended-upgrades always gives me `Marking not allowed <apt_pkg.PackageFile object: filename:'/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.jellyfin.org_ubuntu_dists_focal_main_binary-amd64_Packages'` in the UU log (jellyfin has been removed from the blacklist)

Comment: Conveniently, I wrote a blog post back in February 2020 showing how to figure that out: http://cheesehead-techblog.blogspot.com/2020/02/advanced-unattended-upgrade-ubuntu.html